# Magento 2: Session Information

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, session, magento-2.1.7

Magento 2 has multiple session types. I know that each type gives you access to different information ie current customer information.

The sessions I know of are:

```
\Magento\Backend\Model\Session
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session
\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Session
```

What I need to know is when are these different sessions instantiated / refreshed?

I'm currently having a problem where I add data using ->setData to the Catalog Session. After adding a product to the cart this data (->getData) doesn't exist anymore. Or at least this is what seems to happen.